# Unknown cycle result in java

Tags: java

I want to ask, because this cycle throws me false ?, not know why that is the result.
I think it has to do with floating point

Thank you for your help.

```
double a = 2d;
System.out.println(a);

double b = 2.6d ;
System.out.println(b);

for (int i = 0; i < 6 ; i ++)
{
    a+= 0.1;
}

System.out.println ( a==b ) ;
```

RUN

```
2.0
2.6
false
```

Comment: Use the debugger of your IDE to see exactly what's happening. You will notice how the lack of precision creeps in. I tested your particular code to see the value of `a` rise as follows: 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3000000000000003, ...

Answer (score 1):

You get `false` because you are checking two `double`s for equality. In theory, the two values should be equal. However, `double` representation of `0.1` is inexact, so adding it six times to `2.0` does *not* result in precisely the value of `2.6`. There is a small difference, which results in your comparison failing.

Change the last line to this:

```
System.out.println ( Math.abs(a-b) ) ;
```

to see how small is the magnitude of the error (it is roughly 4.44*10<sup>-16</sup> [(demo)](http://ideone.com/bXGYwR)).

If you would like to perform precise operations on decimal values Java, use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) type instead of `double.

Comment: Thank you very much, but because 0.1 is inexact in `double` ?

Comment: @ChristianEscobarF 0.1 cannot be represented as a finite sum of negative powers of 2 ([good reading on the subject](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/)).